# How dose the click event get registered when you are not clicking the checkbox or using javascript?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

So I'm working on a custom checkbox and I'm using an example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp).
What I can't figure out is how is the click event registered when we are not clicking the checkbox?
As you can see in the image below, the input field is on the right of the label text.

[image]

**UPDATE**
So apperantly there is some magic happening when the checkbox is inside the label tag. But I don't want the label clickable and I need to be able to move the checkbox left and right of the label. So testing Thomas's suggestion, I usd ID and FOR and moved the checkbox outside the label. But this does not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/sstieng/r5y9jqgn/8/

**HTML**

```
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

Comment: The checkbox get the click by the label automatically. I suggest also to tell the label by a FOR attribute which id it has to handle. By this you can also place the label elsewhere. In this case the label has not surround the input span statements.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig Thanks. Because I need to move the checkbox outside the label. Tried using ID and FOR but no luck: https://jsfiddle.net/sstieng/r5y9jqgn/8/

Answer (score 0):

It is because the container doesn't have its specific width and its cover the whole next part on it so if you change your container css to that:

```css
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  width:0px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Now it didn't select outside from the container

**Note: Label is also included in checkBox that is why it get selected by clicking on it**